# Flexform Hook of tx_news not working in TYPO3 8.x

Tags: typo3, hook, tx-news

In my Extension I'm using the backendUtility Hook of the tx_news Extension. It works well in previos versions of TYPO3.

```
/**
 * @param array|string $params
 * @param array $reference
 * @return void
 */
public function updateFlexforms(&$params, &$reference) {
    if ($params['selectedView'] === 'News->calendar') {
        $removedFields = $this->removedFieldsInCalendarView;

        $this->deleteFromStructure($dataStructure, $removedFields);
    }
    
}
```

In TYPO3 8.3 and 8.4 I got the following warning:

> ## 1: PHP Warning: Declaration of \Foo\BarBackendUtility::updateFlexforms(&$params, &$reference) should be compatible with GeorgRinger\News\Hooks\BackendUtility::updateFlexforms(array &$dataStructure, array $row) in /path/to/BackendUtility.php line 0

As it is a hook and it needs these parameters params and reference, I can not change it to the parameters of the original function. This would also lead to an issue.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Just rename your updateFlexform method to a different name.

Problem is because of php7

Comment: I thought so before too, but got this error:
Argument 1 passed to GeorgRinger\News\Hooks\BackendUtility::deleteFromStructure() must be of the type array, null given, called in /BackendUtility.php on line 33

Answer (score 1):

The first answer and the comment in the same thread (both by Georg Ringer) combined leads to the solution:

```
/**
 * @param array $params
 * @param array $reference
 * @return void
 */
public function updateFlexformsDatedNews(&$params, &$reference) {
    if ($params['selectedView'] === 'News->calendar') {
        $removedFields = $this->removedFieldsInCalendarView;
        $this->deleteFromStructure($params['dataStructure'], $removedFields);
    }

}
```

This works with PHP5.6 and 7.0

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP Warrnig message, Becaue in TYPO3 8 core `updateFlexforms()` function pass two parameters with always type array. You need to pass array value in this function.